# SelectBox Jquery Plugin set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm using this great library : https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox i use 4 HTML select that are transformed to new ul / li dropdown

```
$('#s1,#s2,#s3,#s4').selectBox({menuSpeed: 'fast'});
```

## 1 : Changing Css of each box ?

There is only one css for all box, and i need to change min-width for each.Each html select have a new class called selectBox-dropdown

```
$('.selectBox-dropdown').eq(0).attr('style','min-width: 55px;');
```

```
$('.selectBox-dropdown').eq(1).attr('style','min-width: 105px;');
```

I've only found one way to change the style for each box, but i think it's not very handy.
Is it possible to change css with id ? but #s1 is set to display:none when jquery function is applied to all select ...

## 2 : how can i set a value to a selectBox ?

```
$('#s1').selectBox('value', 200); /*doesn't work*/
```

```
$('.selectBox-dropdown').eq(0).attr('html','200'); /*doesn't work*/
```

thanks for all answer.